# PHP pull value of Subkey from Array

Tags: php, arrays, api, command-line-interface

I am currently using a third party API to find out the status of a game server. The API is via PHP and I am able to pull an Array with relevant information towards the servers status.

Here is my API's code:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
require('MulticraftAPI.php');
$api = new MulticraftAPI('http://ip.address.goes.here/multicraft/api.php', 'username', 'apikey');

$a = $api->getServerStatus($argv[1]);

print_r($a);

exit();

?>
```

This script is ran via PHP CLI: php status.php ${server_id} (19 in this case, but that is irrelevant)

The output is the following:

```
[admin@ns5001896 maps]# php status.php 19
Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [errors] => Array
        (
        )

    [data] => Array
        (
            [status] => online
            [onlinePlayers] => 0
            [maxPlayers] => 32
        )

)
```

**My question:
How can I isolate the value of [status] in [data] and print it as the output. Just a single word "online" or "offline"**

I have researched and any normal means from slice'ing the array to dumping vars doesn't work. I am kind of at my wits end here.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Errr.... `$a['data']['status']`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?:

```
echo $a['data']['status'];
```

Comment: Oh wow, this completely passed me up. Thank yo so much! This is exactly what I was looking for and I feel so stupid for not having tried it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Today I have learned that in an 2D array, you need to define where the key is located in order to get the value. I assume that it just looked for the key I specified. IE: I was doing echo $a['status']; and getting errors, but I didn't know why.

Comment: That's true. You have to specify the entire heirarchy.